# Pandas Merge returns empty dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm loading two dataframes from two different csv's, and, try to join them, but for some reason `pd.merge` is not joining the data and is returning empty dataframe. I have tried changing the data types, but still nothing. Appreciate any help.

Sample `mon_apps` dataframe:

```
app_cnts | year | month
16634    | 2018    |  8 
9636     | 2019    |  2 
17402    | 2017    |  8 
17472    | 2017    |  11 
15689    | 2018    |  6
```

Sample `mon_spend` dataframe:

```
channel  | month   | year  | spend
FB       | 1       |  2017 | 0
FB       | 2       |  2017 | 0
FB       | 3       |  2017 | 0
FB       | 4       |  2017 | 0
FB       | 5       |  2017 | 0
```

I change the datatypes(just to be sure it's not an issue) like so:

```
mon_spend[['month', 'year', 'spend']] = mon_spend[['month', 'year', 'spend']].astype(np.int64)
mon_spend['channel'] = mon_spend['channel'].astype(str)
mon_apps = mon_apps.astype(np.int64)
```

I check the datatypes:

```
mon_spend
channel    object
month       int64
year        int64
spend       int64
dtype: object

mon_apps
app_cnts    int64
year        int64
month       int64
dtype: object
```

I join using `pd.merge` like so:

```
pd.merge(mon_apps[['app_cnts', 'year', 'month']], mon_spend, left_on = ["year", "month"], right_on = ["year", "month"])
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

***More data***

```
channel month year spend




FB 2017 1 0 


FB 2017 2 0 


FB 2017 3 0 


FB 2017 4 0 


FB 2017 5 0 


FB 2017 6 0 


FB 2017 7 52514 


FB 2017 8 10198 


FB 2017 9 25408 


FB 2017 10 31333 


FB 2017 11 128071 


FB 2017 12 95160 


FB 2018 1 5001 


FB 2018 2 17929 


FB 2018 3 84548 


FB 2018 4 16414 


FB 2018 5 28282 


FB 2018 6 38430 


FB 2018 7 58757 


FB 2018 8 120722 


FB 2018 9 143766 


FB 2018 10 68400 


FB 2018 11 66984 


FB 2018 12 58228
```

*Some more Info*

```
print (mon_spend[["year", "month"]].sort_values(["year", "month"]).drop_duplicates().values.tolist())
[[2017, 1], [2017, 2], [2017, 3], [2017, 4], [2017, 5]]
​
print (mon_apps[["year", "month"]].sort_values(["year", "month"]).drop_duplicates().values.tolist())

[[2017, 8], [2017, 11], [2018, 6], [2018, 8], [2019, 2]]









[[1, 2017], [1, 2018], [1, 2019], [2, 2017], [2, 2018], [2, 2019], [3, 2017], [3, 2018], [4, 2017], [4, 2018], [5, 2017], [5, 2018], [6, 2017], [6, 2018], [7, 2017], [7, 2018], [8, 2017], [8, 2018], [9, 2017], [9, 2018], [10, 2017], [10, 2018], [11, 2017], [11, 2018], [12, 2017], [12, 2018]]
[[2017, 1], [2017, 2], [2017, 3], [2017, 4], [2017, 5], [2017, 6], [2017, 7], [2017, 8], [2017, 9], [2017, 10], [2017, 11], [2017, 12], [2018, 1], [2018, 2], [2018, 3], [2018, 4], [2018, 5], [2018, 6], [2018, 7], [2018, 8], [2018, 9], [2018, 10], [2018, 11], [2018, 12], [2019, 1], [2019, 2], [2019, 3]]




Out[18]:

[[2017, 8], [2017, 11], [2018, 6], [2018, 8], [2019, 2]]
```

Comment: only month which matches is 2, however the year for that month doesnot match, so no results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The month and year is exchanged in the files you are merging try swapping the keys while merging or rename them before the merge:

```
mon_apps.merge(complete_file, left_on=["year", "month"],right_on=['month','year'])
```

Comment: Doesn't this mean that you're joining 'month' with 'year'? If you pass on=columns without specifying right and left, doesn't that mean join on these columns assuming they exist in both data frames?

Comment: @Boris i didnot get you, instead of `on=`, the solution has `left_on=` and `right_on` which is specific to the left and right dfs

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use left_on and right_on here when the columns have the same names in the right database as in the left. If you just pass on = ["year", "month"] instead of what you did, then that should work right?

Comment: @Boris no, the original data had month and year swapped in one of the dataframes :) hence this solution.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Problem is there are swaped years with month columns.

Better solution is rename - by function `rename` or rename headers in file:

```
df = pd.merge(mon_apps, mon_spend.rename(columns={'year':'month','month':'year'}), 
              on = ["year", "month"])
print (df)
   app_cnts  year  month hannel   spend
0     16634  2018      8     FB  120722
1     17402  2017      8     FB   10198
2     17472  2017     11     FB  128071
3     15689  2018      6     FB   38430
```

Because not columns names with `prefixes`:

```
df = mon_apps.merge(mon_spend, left_on=["year", "month"],right_on=['month','year'])
print (df)
   app_cnts  year_x  month_x hannel  month_y  year_y   spend
0     16634    2018        8     FB     2018       8  120722
1     17402    2017        8     FB     2017       8   10198
2     17472    2017       11     FB     2017      11  128071
3     15689    2018        6     FB     2018       6   38430
```

Comment: I have just added some more data for `mon_spend`, and if you see 2018 8th month is matching.

Comment: `[[2017, 8], [2017, 11], [2018, 6], [2018, 8], [2019, 2]]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193745/discussion-between-ahsan-and-anky-91).